# Count cells containing certain value that have a specific format in excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, count, formatting, countif

I need to count the number of cells in my spreadsheet that are both highlighted and have a certain value. I am new to VBA though so am not sure how to combine the two conditions. It's not working but my thinking so far is below. Any idea why it's not working?

```
Function Countif_by_color_number(r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range) As Long

 Application.Volatile
 Dim x As Long
 Dim cel As Range

 x = 0

 For Each cel In r1
     If cel.Interior.Color = r2.Interior.Color And cel.Value = r3.Value Then
             x = x + 1
     End If
 Next

 Countif_by_color_number = x

End Function
```

Comment: Are the cells colored using conditional formatting?  And are you using this as a function in a worksheet, or is it being called from VBA?

Comment: It's working fine, tested.  Did your put your function in a module?

Comment: The cells are colored manually using the cell fill formatting.

Comment: Oh my bad, the cell value I was testing it with resulted in a 0 which I wasn't expecting. I just checked and it is fine. Thanks anyway!